# Command not properly ended

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

What is the problem with this statement? I am getting the error "command not properly ended":

```
update subjectinfo set subject_name = '"
  + textBoxSubjectNameUpdate.Text
  + "' , subject_abbreviation = '"
  + textBoxSubjectAbbreviationUpdate.Text
  + "where subject_code = '"
  + textBoxSubjectCodeUpdate.Text + "'"
```

Comment: You're just missing a space before `where`, and a closing single quote for the preceding Text value. You're also inviting SQL injection; please consider using bind variables instead of putting user input directly into your statement.

Comment: Besides the fact that it's vulnerable to sql injection?

Comment: First of all, use parameterized queries. Second of all, if you insist on not doing that, at least use parameterized strings

Comment: thanks... i will make the changes ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a closing single quote after your textBoxSubjectAbbreviationUpdate.Text value, and then a space between that and `where`:

```
update subjectinfo set subject_name = '"
  + textBoxSubjectNameUpdate.Text
  + "' , subject_abbreviation = '"
  + textBoxSubjectAbbreviationUpdate.Text
  + "' where subject_code = '"
  + textBoxSubjectCodeUpdate.Text + "'"
```

You're also inviting SQL injection; please consider using [bind variables](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B25329_01/doc/appdev.102/b25312/building_odp.htm#CEGCGDAB) instead of putting user input directly into your statement.

Answer (score 2):

This

```
+ "where subject_code = '"
```

should read

```
+ "' where subject_code = '"

   ^ quote and space here
```

But please use parameters. Do not build your SQL that way, it will lead to successful [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Answer (score 1):

Missing a single quote in the end and before "where":

```
update subjectinfo set subject_name = '"
  + textBoxSubjectNameUpdate.Text
  + "' , subject_abbreviation = '"
  + textBoxSubjectAbbreviationUpdate.Text
  + "' where subject_code = '"
  + textBoxSubjectCodeUpdate.Text + "'
```

Comment: Yeah, I noticed now, I was not sure if he wanted the "where" to be part of the insert. I've corrected it now. Thanks!

Comment: You've still left a stray single quote at the end.

Comment: Damn it! Multitasking! :)

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you should not use SQL statements within the code to avoid SQL injection.

The above specific case, can be written using a StringBuilder class which is more clean and less performance burden.

```
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("update subjectinfo set subject_name = '");
            sb.Append(textBoxSubjectNameUpdate.Text);
            sb.Append("' , subject_abbreviation = '");
            sb.Append(textBoxSubjectAbbreviationUpdate.Text);
            sb.Append("' where subject_code = '");
            sb.Append(textBoxSubjectCodeUpdate.Text);
            sb.Append("'");

var script  sb.ToString()
```